# Accessing DocuSign templates

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am trying to access the templates Rest API documented here: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/

With my sandbox integrator key I can easily login and get my demo base_url at `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`.

I have successfully connected to envelopes Rest API, but when I connect to templates Rest API I get:

```
The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.
<PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED>
```

Is the templates Rest API not accessible to the demo/sandbox integrator keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are passing the correct Authorization Header based on the authentication type you are using. See more info [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)

---

**Sandbox Features**

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#create-sandbox)

> Developer sandboxes are free, they don't expire, and they have enterprise level features enabled.

Demo environment will have all the features that DocuSign offers.